# MS Access 2003 Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a macro that eventually uses the `DoCmd.TransferText` function. Here is the error below:

```
Cannot find object. Make sure the object exists and you spell its name and path correctly
```

I've used this method before to create a text file and add contents to it either from a table or a query. 
Can someone correct me on this but doesn't the Transfer Text method create the file if it doesn't already exist?

Here is the code where i call it:

```
'Create Dispense File
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "DispenseExportSpec", "qryExport", DispenseFileName
Call Sleep(5000)

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportDispenseCFSpec", "qryExportDispenseCF",     ExportDispenseCFName
Call Sleep(5000)
```

(It fails on the first) This can't/shouldn't be a permissions issue as I have full read/write/edit abilities over the folder and its subfolders; it's not a path issue as I've verified multiple times, so what is the the problem here?

Access Version: MS Access 2003

Thanks

Comment: Check if DoCmd is available?  Are you sure these are the lines the error is happening on?  Can you show more code?

Comment: @TobyAllen I'm certain this is where the error is occurring because it executes right up to this point - i placed a breakpoint at this exact line then stepped over using F8 and it threw the error

Comment: Have you tried removing the spec argument and let it use the default? The documentation on that seems wonky. Just do a `DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryExport", DispenseFileName`? There seems like there are a lot of conditions on that to get it to work. Maybe if it works you can narrow your debugging there?

Comment: @Bmo Will try that now

Comment: Great catch Bmo - the problem did lie with the Export Specification. I removed it, ran the code and it created the text file fine. Because I need the spec I had to recreate via the wizard in MS 2007 (The option dodesn't seem to be available in MS Access 2003) and then added the spec back in. Fixed now :D I'll add this as an answer when I can

Comment: @Bmo add your suggestion as an answers so it can be marked as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the spec argument and let it use the default? The documentation on that seems wonky. Just do a `DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryExport", DispenseFileName`